# How can I use summarise_each for correlations in dplyr?

Tags: r, dplyr

A dataframe has 20 columns, and I want to find the correlation of column "a" with rest of the columns.

How can I do it using dplyr?

I know how to do individual correlations such as this:

```
test %>%
  dplyr::summarize(cor(a, b))
```

Or summarise_each for mean.

But how can I do it for correlation?

Two use cases:

1. Where it calculates correlations with *every* other column in the dataframe.
2. Where it calculates correlations with columns I mention.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The corrr package uses dplyr as a backend (and so easily works with it) to do just this via `correlate() %>% focus()`:

```
library(corrr)

mtcars %>% 
  correlate() %>% 
  focus(mpg)
#> # A tibble: 10 × 2
#>    rowname        mpg
#>      <chr>      <dbl>
#> 1      cyl -0.8521620
#> 2     disp -0.8475514
#> 3       hp -0.7761684
#> 4     drat  0.6811719
#> 5       wt -0.8676594
#> 6     qsec  0.4186840
#> 7       vs  0.6640389
#> 8       am  0.5998324
#> 9     gear  0.4802848
#> 10    carb -0.5509251

mtcars %>% 
  select(mpg, disp, hp) %>% 
  correlate() %>% 
  focus(mpg)
#> # A tibble: 2 × 2
#>   rowname        mpg
#>     <chr>      <dbl>
#> 1    disp -0.8475514
#> 2      hp -0.7761684
```

`focus()` acts like `dplyr::select()`, except that it excludes any remaining columns from the rows. If interested, take a look at `focus_.cor_df()` on GitHub [here](https://github.com/drsimonj/corrr/blob/master/R/cor_df.R).

Comment: When I am using the first one, I get this error: Error in pmatch(use, c("all.obs", "complete.obs", "pairwise.complete.obs",  :

Comment: How are you using it? Did you directly copy code+paste code from GitHub or did you install corrr?

Comment: I have installed corrr

Comment: There are some non-numeric columns if I may add. I don't need to use them.

Comment: Perhaps this is the reason. Try to drop those columns first (eg `dat %>% select(-cat1, -cat2, ...) %>% correlate() ...`) or select the columns you're interested in like in my second example above.

Answer (score 1):

Do not quite understand the two use cases which I think you may need the `combn` function but for:

> I want to find the correlation of column "a" with rest of the columns.

You can do something like this, directly pass the column `a` as one of the parameter to the `cor` function and use `.` to represent the rest of columns:

```
library(dplyr)
df <- data.frame(a = rnorm(5), b = rnorm(5), c = rnorm(5))
df %>% summarise_each(funs(cor(., df$a)), -a)

#           b          c
# 1 0.1997687 -0.3541925
```

If there are non-numeric columns and you are only interested in numeric columns, you may need the `summarise_if` function and specify the condition to be numeric, in which case only numeric columns will be summarized and corresponding correlation coefficients calculated :

```
df <- data.frame(a = rnorm(5), b = rnorm(5), c = rnorm(5), d = letters[1:5])
df %>% summarise_if(is.numeric, funs(cor(., df$a)))
#  a         b           c
#1 1 0.1153882 -0.03117205
```